# ES lint not working after trying to install it to MERN stack project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, eslint

In my client directory (React), I ran

`npm install eslint --save-dev`

then I ran

`npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev`

I created an `.eslintrc` file and added to it

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "extends": ["eslint:all", "plugin:react/all"]
}
```

I know that ES lint should run upon every commit... however it seems to never be invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I know that ES lint should run upon every commit" are you sure? I think you should configure pre-commit to make it work like this.

Comment: I, indeed, am not, lol. You seem to be right, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ESLint to automatically fix your errors on commit, you can use [`lint-staged`](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) with [`husky`](https://github.com/typicode/husky), which manages git hooks.

```
npm install --save-dev lint-staged husky
```

```
// @ package.json
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": ["eslint --fix", "git add"]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Without it, you only get linting during compile time.

> You can check my [`eslint-config` readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dennisvash/eslint-config) to how to configure `eslint` with `prettier` in `vscode`.